# You should and must participate in the game,[shouldn't or mustn't]you?

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

> You should and must participate in the game. [Shouldn't you] or
> [mustn't you]?

This question's tag is perplexing and baffling to me.

Comment: It's a poor choice of a sentence to put a tag question on. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either could work, but I'd go for "must" because of the recency effect.

Also, because "must" is a stronger obligation, it sounds as though the two terms aren't merely coordinated, but that you changed your mind and replaced "should" by "must".